# elasticsearch - moving from multi servers to one server

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a cluster of 5 servers for elasticsearch, all with the same version of elasticsearch.

I need to move all data from servers 2, 3, 4, 5 to server 1.

How can I do it?

How can I know which server has data at all?

After change of _cluster/settings with:

```
PUT _cluster/settings
{
  "persistent" : {
    "cluster.routing.allocation.require._host" : "server1"
  }
}
```

I get for:    **curl -GET http://localhost:9200/_cat/allocation?v**

the following:

```
shards disk.indices disk.used disk.avail disk.total disk.percent host    ip      node
     6       54.5gb   170.1gb      1.9tb      2.1tb            7 *.*.*.* *.*.*.* node-5
     6       50.4gb   167.4gb      1.9tb      2.1tb            7 *.*.*.* *.*.*.* node-3
     6       22.6gb   139.8gb        2tb      2.1tb            6 *.*.*.* *.*.*.* node-2
     6       49.8gb   166.6gb      1.9tb      2.1tb            7 *.*.*.* *.*.*.* node-4
     6       54.8gb   172.1gb      1.9tb      2.1tb            7 *.*.*.* *.*.*.* node-1
```

and for:    **GET _cluster/settings?include_defaults**

the following:

```
#! Deprecation: [node.max_local_storage_nodes] setting was deprecated in Elasticsearch and will be removed in a future release!
{
  "persistent" : {
    "cluster" : {
      "routing" : {
        "allocation" : {
          "require" : {
            "_host" : "server1"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "transient" : { },
  "defaults" : {
    "cluster" : {
      "max_voting_config_exclusions" : "10",
      "auto_shrink_voting_configuration" : "true",
      "election" : {
        "duration" : "500ms",
        "initial_timeout" : "100ms",
        "max_timeout" : "10s",
        "back_off_time" : "100ms",
        "strategy" : "supports_voting_only"
      },
      "no_master_block" : "write",
      "persistent_tasks" : {
        "allocation" : {
          "enable" : "all",
          "recheck_interval" : "30s"
        }
      },
      "blocks" : {
        "read_only_allow_delete" : "false",
        "read_only" : "false"
      },
      "remote" : {
        "node" : {
          "attr" : ""
        },
        "initial_connect_timeout" : "30s",
        "connect" : "true",
        "connections_per_cluster" : "3"
      },
      "follower_lag" : {
        "timeout" : "90000ms"
      },
      "routing" : {
        "use_adaptive_replica_selection" : "true",
        "rebalance" : {
          "enable" : "all"
        },
        "allocation" : {
          "node_concurrent_incoming_recoveries" : "2",
          "node_initial_primaries_recoveries" : "4",
          "same_shard" : {
            "host" : "false"
          },
          "total_shards_per_node" : "-1",
          "shard_state" : {
            "reroute" : {
              "priority" : "NORMAL"
            }
          },
          "type" : "balanced",
          "disk" : {
            "threshold_enabled" : "true",
            "watermark" : {
              "low" : "85%",
              "flood_stage" : "95%",
              "high" : "90%"
            },
            "include_relocations" : "true",
            "reroute_interval" : "60s"
          },
          "awareness" : {
            "attributes" : [ ]
          },
          "balance" : {
            "index" : "0.55",
            "threshold" : "1.0",
            "shard" : "0.45"
          },
          "enable" : "all",
          "node_concurrent_outgoing_recoveries" : "2",
          "allow_rebalance" : "indices_all_active",
          "cluster_concurrent_rebalance" : "2",
          "node_concurrent_recoveries" : "2"
        }
      },
     ...
      "nodes" : {
        "reconnect_interval" : "10s"
      },
      "service" : {
        "slow_master_task_logging_threshold" : "10s",
        "slow_task_logging_threshold" : "30s"
      },
      ...
      "name" : "cluster01",
      ...
      "max_shards_per_node" : "1000",
      "initial_master_nodes" : [ ],
      "info" : {
        "update" : {
          "interval" : "30s",
          "timeout" : "15s"
        }
      }
    },
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [shard allocation filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-cluster.html#cluster-shard-allocation-filtering) to move all your data to server 1.

Simply run this:

```
PUT _cluster/settings
{
  "persistent" : {
    "cluster.routing.allocation.require._name" : "node-1",
    "cluster.routing.allocation.exclude._name" : "node-2,node-3,node-4,node-5"
  }
}
```

Instead of `_name` you can also use `_ip` or `_host` depending on what is more practical for you.

After running this command, all primary shards will migrate to server1 (the replicas will be unassigned). You just need to make sure that server1 has enough storage space to store all the primary shards.

If you want to get rid of the unassigned replicas (and get back to green state), simply run this:

```
PUT _all/_settings
{
  "index" : {
    "number_of_replicas" : 0
  }
}
```

Comment: With _host I need to use what I get with the hostname linux command. correct?

Comment: I did it and get good response, but when I check the health I still get 5 for node.total and for node.data

Comment: it's normal, because all nodes are still up. Use `GET /_cat/allocation?v` to verify that all your shards are on server1

Comment: I get 6 shards for each node. In addition, I didn't see anything run after the PUT command, I only get a quick response for the change. Maybe I need to restart the system?

Comment: No need to restart anything. Please update your question with what you get out of the `_cat/allocation` command. Also can you show what you get from `GET _cluster/settings?include_defaults` ?

Comment: I see in the settings that you kept `server1`, did you use your real hostname?

Comment: Ok, can you also add the following information `GET _cluster/allocation/explain?include_disk_info&include_yes_decisions` please?

Comment: And also `GET _cat/indices?v` and `GET _cat/shards?v` thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218428/discussion-between-refaeljan-and-val).